# C++ Winapi CreateProcess issue with command line

Tags: c++, winapi, parameters, null, createprocess

I'm using `CreateProcess` this way:

```
resultCreate = CreateProcess(Command, CommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

//"Command" contains the executable file to execute
//"CommandLine" contains the parameters to pass to that executable
```

The parameters are the following:

```
Param1: "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\file.dll"
Param2: "file" (module name)
Param3: " " (blank)
```

So the full CommandLine string would be:

```
"C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\file.dll" file " "
```

`CreateProcess` runs the executable successfully and applies the first two parameters, but when reaches the third one, it throws error

```
The specified process could not be found.
Function " " could not be called, due to " " doesn't exist in the DLL "(null)"
```

How can I pass the desired parameters correctly?

Comment: CreateProcess just runs the executable. Anything beyond that is an issue with the executable. But note that the first part of the command line should be the executable again.

Comment: The executable expects the first parameter to be a DLL, otherwise, it won't run. The executable runs successfully but the problem comes when tries to execute the " " parameter.

Comment: Calling `CreateProcess` on a DLL file doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm not creating a process on a DLL. I'm creating a process on an executable, but that executable needs a DLL why wouldn't it make sense?

Comment: Many executables reference DLLs, but those dependencies are resolved by the OS loader. There's no need to specify DLLs on the command line. The error is generated by the new process. Risking a guess I'd assume that the process expects the first string in the command line to be the executable image. If you want to play it safe, pass the quoted command as the first argument of your command line. Pseudo code: `CreateProcess(Command, '\"'+Command+"\" "+CommandLine, ... );`

Comment: @IInspectable: "*There's no need to specify DLLs on the command line*" - you don't know what the parameter in question actually represents. Maybe the exe loads the DLL dynamically? Maybe the exe (un)registers or deletes/modifies the DLL. You can pass a DLL filename to `regsvr32`, is that wrong? You don't know what this program is actually doing, so saying that it makes no sense to specify a DLL filename as a parameter is basing your opinion on an uninformed assumption.  In any case, your pseudo-code is the correct solution to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When both `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` are used, you need to include the executable path as the first parameter of your `lpCommandLine` value, even though you are specifying the executable path in the `lpApplication` value.  The `lpCommandLine` is passed as-is to the spawned process, and most RTLs (especially C-based RTLs, but others as well) expect the first command-line parameter to be the executable path since that is how command-line consoles operate.  This is even mentioned in the [`CreateProcess()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx):

> If both *lpApplicationName* and *lpCommandLine* are non-NULL, the null-terminated string pointed to by *lpApplicationName* specifies the module to execute, and the null-terminated string pointed to by *lpCommandLine* specifies the command line. The new process can use [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) to retrieve the entire command line. **Console processes written in C can use the argc and argv arguments to parse the command line. Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line.**

This is also covered in MSDN Support:

[INFO: Understanding CreateProcess and Command-line Arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/175986)

> Behavior of CreateProcess() When Creating a 32-bit Process
>
> Case 1:
>
> If the ApplicationName parameter is passed and the CommandLine parameter is NULL, then the ApplicationName parameter is also used as the CommandLine. This does not mean that you can pass additional command-line parameters in ApplicationName string. For example, the following call will fail with a "File Not Found" error:
>
> ```
> CreateProcess( "c:\\MyApp.exe Param1 Param2", NULL, ... )
> ```
>
> Case 2:
>
> On the other hand, if the CommandLine parameter is non-NULL and the ApplicationName parameter is NULL, then the API attempts to extract the application name from the CommandLine parameter.
>
> Case 3:
>
> The flexibility of the CreateProcess() function (and a possible point of confusion) arises when you pass a valid string pointer to both the ApplicationName and CommandLine parameters. This allows you to specify the application to be executed as well as the complete command line that is passed to the application. One might assume that the command line passed to the created application is a composite of the ApplicationName and CommandLine parameters, but this is not the case. As a result, a process created by CreateProcess can receive a value other than its .exe name as its "argv[0]" parameter. The following is an example of a call to CreateProcess that produces this "abnormal" behavior:
>
> ```
> CreateProcess( "c:\\MyApp.exe", "Param1 Param2 Param3", ...)
> ```
>
> MyApp's arguments will be as follow:
>
> ```
> argv[0] == "Param1"
> argv[1] == "Param2"
> argv[2] == "Param3"
> ```
>
> NOTE: ANSI specifications require that argv[0] should be equal to the application name, but CreateProcess gives the calling application the flexibility to override this rule for 32-bit processes.

Case #3 applies to your situation.

Use something like this instead:

```
std::string Command = "<exe path>";
std::string CommandLine = "\"" + Command + "\" <parameters>";

// std::string::c_str() returns a const pointer. The first parameter
// of CreateProcessA() is const, but the second parameter must be a
// non-const pointer to writable memory, because CreateProcessW() can
// modify the data...
//
resultCreate = CreateProcessA(Command.c_str(), &CommandLine[0], ...);
```

```
std::wstring Command = L"<exe path>";
std::wstring CommandLine = L"\"" + Command + L"\" <parameters>";

// std::wstring::c_str() returns a const pointer. The first parameter
// of CreateProcessW() is const, but the second parameter must be a
// non-const pointer to writable memory, because CreateProcessW() can
// modify the data...
//
resultCreate = CreateProcessW(Command.c_str(), &CommandLine[0], ...);
```

Alternatively, omit `lpApplicationName` and specify the complete command line to `lpCommandLine` only:

```
std::string CommandLine = "\"<exe path>\" <parameters>";
resultCreate = CreateProcessA(NULL, &CommandLine[0], ...);
```

```
std::wstring CommandLine = L"\"<exe path>\" <parameters>";
resultCreate = CreateProcessW(NULL, &CommandLine[0], ...);
```

Comment: `c_str` is const, but second arg is modifiable. Why propose ANSI rather than Unicode.

Comment: The second parameter is only modified in `CreateProcessW()` but not in `CreateProcessA()` (this is documented). You can use `&CommandLine[0]` instead if the compiler will not accept `CommandLine.c_str()`. In any case I used `CreateProcessA()` in my examples because I read the OP's example as using `char*` strings. If the OP is using `wchar_t*` strings instead, simply change to `CreateProcessW()` (`CommandLine` is not a `const` variable in either case, so `CreateProcessW()` would be free to modify it without crashing).

Comment: There's no if about it. `c_str()` returns const. So how is it going to compile?

Comment: That is why I mentioned `&CommandLine[0]` as an alternative.  You can also use `const_cast` since *most* `c_str()` implementations simply return a pointer to the string's internal data (yes, I am aware that the C++ standard allows `c_str()` implementations to return a different pointer).

Comment: Well, in my view it would be better to get the code right in the answer, that's all I really meant